# Regular Expression for comma separeted, how to wrap the word with html tag and extract numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

Original string

```
var string = '[[[15]]]未分類,[[[1800449870]]]Special Clothing,[[[2100]]]Accessories,[[[610]]]third cat';
```

1st string that I want to create

```
var string1 = '<span>未分類</span>,<span>Clothing</span>,<span>Accessories</span>,<span>third cat</span>';
```

2nd string that I want to create

```
var string2 = '15,1800449870,2100,610';
```

- Numbers are always wrapped by "[[[" and "]]]".
- Numbers are "natural number", no negative value or zero.
- Number of digits is unknown.
- Words after the number could be English, Japanese, Chinese, ... etc.

I could extract the words with following code but don't know how to wrap with <span>

```
var string1 = string.replace(/\[\[\[\d+\]\]\]/g, '');
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a regex replacement:

```js
var string = '[[[15]]]未分類,[[[1800449870]]]Special Clothing,[[[2100]]]Accessories,[[[610]]]third cat';
var output = string.replace(/\[\[\[.*?\]\]\]([^,]+)/g, '<span>$1</span>');
console.log(output);

var output2 = string.replace(/\[\[\[(\d+?)\]\]\][^[]+/g, '$1,').slice(0, -1);
console.log(output2);
```

The general approach for both strings is to match the `[[[...]]]` terms, capturing either what follows those tags, or the number which occurs inside the tags.  Then, we build the replacement using the capture group.  Note the call to `slice` in the second number CSV string is needed to trim off the final separating comma, which we don't want to appear in the output.

Comment: It worked fine! Thank you so much for your explanation. Actually I was wondering how to remove the last comma.